# Redirect in Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I can not get this redirect to work when my button executes this function.
In this function it is posting two different forms upon submit through subbut, that is working but it just remains on the page.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#subbut").click(function() {
            $.post($("#verify").attr("action"), $("#verify").serialize(),
              function(data) {
                $.post($("#optinform").attr("action"), $("#optinform").serialize(),
                  function(data) {
                      window.location = "http://redirect-to-page.com"
                    });
              });
          });
      }); =
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?  If not, put an alert right before the window.location to make sure you are getting in there.  Also, what's with that `=` sign hanging out at the end in no mans land?

Comment: You might find my jQuery plugin useful https://github.com/michaelpapworth/jQuery.navigate

Answer (score 2):

instead of `window.location = "http://redirect-to-page.com"`,

try `window.location.href = "http://redirect-to-page.com";`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me.
Even though `window.location` will mostly work, I think it should be `window.location.href`.
Which browser do you use?

-

Did you noticed your typo error? '=' at the end of the second to last line shouldn't be there.